# using subprocess module in python to run isql command

Tags: python, subprocess

I have to run isql command using python.

Currently i'm doing it in this way

```
 ps = subprocess.Popen("""./isql -I /app/sybase/interfaces_global -S %s -U %s -P %s -D %s -s "|" -w 99999 <<EOF
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 %s
 go
 EOF""" %(mdbserver,muserid,mpassword,mdatabase,User_Query),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True,cwd=sybase_path)
```

But this method is dependent on the /tmp directory of my server because of the here document, everytime when i run it, it creates a tmp file in the /tmp directory and when the /tmp directory is full the script fails to run the Query onto the database.

How can i use the same command with `shell=False`, So that i can get rid of the here document """ and the temporary file creation.

this doesn't works

```
ps = subprocess.Popen("./isql","-I","/app/sybase/interfaces_global","-S",mdbserver,"-U",muserid,"-P",mpassword,"-D",mdatabase,"-s","|","-w","99999","\nSET NOCOUNT ON\n",User_Query,"\ngo",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False,cwd=sybase_path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the here-document by setting `stdin=PIPE` and providing the input as a string using `.communicate()` method as [@Hans Then suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25035328/4279):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from textwrap import dedent

isql = Popen(['./isql', '-I', '/app/sybase/...',
              '-S', mdbserver,
              '-U', muserid, ...,
              '-w', '99999'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, cwd=sybase_path)
output = isql.communicate(dedent("""\
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    {}
    go
""".format(User_Query)))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the subprocess `communicate()` command. You can use it to send isql commands to the interpreter.